# How to insert multiple skills at once?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have following table

**skills**

```
id|skill_name|category
```

**user table**

```
id | username
```

**user_skill**

```
id|userid|skill_id|rating
```

I want to insert all skills of ther user into `add_skill` table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-design">
<form class="form-signin" method="POST" action="{{url('admin/my-skills')}}">
            {!! Form::token() !!}


            <tr class="table-header" >

                <th rowspan="2">ID</th>

                <th rowspan="2"> Skills</th>

                <th colspan="5"  >Rate Your Skills Out of 5</th>



            </tr>
<tr class="radio-content table-header">
      <th  class="radio-content">1 star</th>
      <th class="radio-content">2 star</th>
      <th class="radio-content">3 star</th>
         <th class="radio-content">4 star</th>
            <th class="radio-content">5 star


            </th>
    </tr>

<?php $i=1; ?>

@foreach($data as $val)
            <tr>

                <td>{{$i}}</td>

                <td>{{$val->skill_name}}</td>

                <td class="radio-content"><input type="radio" name="q{{$i}}" value="1" /></td>
                <td class="radio-content"><input type="radio" name="q{{$i}}" value="2"/></td>
                <td class="radio-content"><input type="radio" name="q{{$i}}" value="3"/></td>
                <td class="radio-content"><input type="radio" name="q{{$i}}" value="4" /></td>
                <td class="radio-content"><input type="radio" name="q{{$i}}" value="5"/></td>


            </tr>
            {{$i++}}
@endforeach

            <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><p class="submit-label">Submit</p></td>
                <td colspan="5"><button type="submit" class="btn-new btn-submit">Submit Your Skills</button></td>
            </tr>



</form>
    </table>
```

[image]
When I submit the form, I need to insert all skill in `add_skill` table, but my problem is I can't set the same name for all input radios. If I set name same then I can choose only one item.

Can any one tell how I can achieve this? if am wrong in my table structure please guide me.

Comment: You can also implement meta table concept here..

Comment: @Vijay Sankhat.can you provide an example ?

Answer (score 2):

Despite what Aniruddha Chakraborty says, you *can* insert multiple skills in one query. The table schema you have is fine, and is what would be recommended in this scenario: a join table with two foreigns keys: one pointing to the user and another to the skill. Although as per Laravel conventions, your life would be made a lot easier if it were named `skill_user`.

When you submit the form, you’ll get an array of skill IDs. If your user model has a `skills()` method that defines the `belongsToMany` relation, then you can insert them in one go like this:

```
$user->skills()->sync($request->q);
```

To make this easier to read, I’d rename the field in your HTML to be “skills” (i.e. `<input name="skills[]" />`). That way it’s a bit more descriptive, and you code would look like this:

```
$user->skills()->sync($request->skills);
```

Easier to read, as “skills” makes a lot more sense than just “q”.

Comment: .thank you for the answer.yes you are right i can use skill_user.my question is how to insert from this form.how to name input radio?

Comment: I’ve given you the answer to those questions in my post.